# DBPedia live endpoint giving 504 or 503 exception

Tags: java, sparql, dbpedia

I am using java code to write sparql query for DBPedia. http://dbpedia.org/sparql and also http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql both worked fine but suddenly after few days today I am facing problem because live endpoint giving 504 or sometimes 503 httpException.

Comment: Both are shared, public resources maintained by somebody for free. It's obvious that maintenance can happen suddenly. The most reliable solution is to setup your own DBpedia instance locally. The data and free triple stores are available for you

Comment: Learn more about DBpedia public access policies in the most recent [Usage Report](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/dbpedia-usage-report-as-of-2018-01-01-8cae1b81ca71). If you need guaranteed uptime, consider spinning up your own mirror via the [DBpedia Snapshot AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07BQKYGYQ).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about it!

Answer (score 0):

It means the server is temporarily down or under maintenance. Try again later. (It seems to be working now.)